# React/Javascript get max value and respective label from array and render

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the below array 'predictScore' and able to get the max value using `const max = predictScore.reduce((acc, item) => acc = acc > item.prob ? acc : item.prob, 0);`

How do i get the max value and associated label and render in a p tag as:
`<p>The image uploaded is {max} percentage of {label} </p>`

```
predictScore = [

    0: {label: "other", prob: 0.03129873052239418}
    1: {label: "dog", prob: 0.033306580036878586}
    2: {label: "cat", prob: 0.9353946447372437}

]
```

So based on the above cat score is 93% so the final output should be The image uploaded is 93% percentage of a cat

Comment: I mentioned what i have tried which is const max = predictScore.reduce((acc, item) => acc = acc > item.prob ? acc : item.prob, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, just return the entire `item` object and check the `prob` property in the reduce callback.

```js
const predictScore = [
  { label: "other", prob: 0.03129873052239418 },
  { label: "dog", prob: 0.033306580036878586 },
  { label: "cat", prob: 0.9353946447372437 }
];

const { label, prob } = predictScore.reduce(
  (acc, item) => (acc.prob > item.prob ? acc : item),
  {}
);

console.log(
  `<p>The image uploaded is ${Math.round(
    prob * 100
  )}% percentage of ${label} </p>`
);
```